# Spring 3.x MVC Controller:Adding attribute to Request/Session

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am new to Spring and having a basic question related to the Spring 3 MVC controller class.

I have this below method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("contacts", new EmployeeForm());
    map.put("contactList", employeeService.listEmployee());
    return "contacts";
}
```

In the JSP file, I an accessing the `contactList` using this below piece of code:

```
<c:forEach items="${contactList}" var="contact">
<tr>
    <td>${contact.lastname}, ${contact.firstname} </td>
    <td>${contact.email}</td>
    <td>${contact.telephone}</td>
    <td><a href="delete/${contact.id}">delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**My confusion:**

I have not added that `contactList` in a session or request attribute in my controller class, then how am I able to access the same in JSP file using `${contactList}` ?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Map` argument you have in your controller handler method is effectively used as a map of model attributes.

Model attributes are (typically) added as `HttpServletRequest` attributes before the view is rendered.

This is explained in the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

> The following are the supported method arguments:
>
> - `java.util.Map` / `org.springframework.ui.Model` /
>     `org.springframework.ui.ModelMap` for enriching the implicit model that
>     is exposed to the web view.

Comment: @user182944 Which part? Anything you add to the `Map` will, down the line, be added as a request attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is providing you a Map, or basically a view model, which you can populate in your controller handler method.  After your handler completes, Spring adds anything you added to the Map to the jsp context so that they can be accessed as normal context variables.  I believe the variables are added to the 'request' scope for access by the JSP code, but I am not certain, as it might be 'page' scope.

Because the handler and view rendering are being handled (managed by Spring) in the same request, there is no need to store any of the model information in the session.